# using python re to find url's that contain x

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

using python 2.7.3, urllib and re, i am looking for urls that contain:

```
href="/dirone/Dir_Two/dirthree/"
```

where the url might be, for example:

```
href="/dirone/Dir_Two/dirthree/5678-random-stuff-here-letters-and-numbers"
```

and am wanting to return:

```
"/dirone/Dir_Two/dirthree/5678-random-stuff-here-letters-and-numbers"
```

using this tool:

http://www.jslab.dk/tools.regex.php

i generated the regex to be:

```
/^href\="\/dirone\/Dir_Two\/dirthree\/"$/im
```

could this regex therefore be used with python and re in the following way:

```
object_name = re.findall('/^href\="\/dirone\/Dir_Two\/dirthree\/"$/im',url)
for single_url in object_name:
    do something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to drop the `^` anchor; I doubt the `href` will ever be at the start of a line.

You don't need the `/im` part, those should be replaced by `re.` flag constants. You have Perl regular expression syntax there, Python doesn't have the specialized `/.../flags` syntax.

As such there are too many escapes and no actual Python string. And you don't actually include the `5678-random-stuff-here-letters-and-numbers` part.

Use this instead:

```
object_name = re.findall(r'href="(/dirone/Dir_Two\/dirthree/[^"/]*)"', url, re.I)
```

I dropped the multiline flag since we are no longer matching on the start of a string having dropped the `^`. I added a group (`(...)`) around the path so that `findall()` returns those and not the whole match. The `[^"/]*` part matches any character than is not a quote or slash to capture the filename part but not another directory name.

Short demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> example = '<a href="/dirone/Dir_Two/dirthree/5678-random-stuff-here-letters-and-numbers">'
>>> re.findall(r'href="(/dirone/Dir_Two\/dirthree/[^"/]*)"', example, re.I)
['/dirone/Dir_Two/dirthree/5678-random-stuff-here-letters-and-numbers']
```

Comment: I believe you meant ``re.M | re.I``.

Comment: @Bogdan: I did, but then removed `re.M` because it is meaningless without the start-of-line caret.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Martijn's answer, but using `beautifulsoup` on the assumption you've got HTML.

```
data = '<a href="/dirone/Dir_Two/dirthree/5678-random-stuff-here-letters-and-numbers">Content</a>'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print [el['href'] for el in soup('a', href=re.compile('^/dirone/Dir_Two/.*'))]
```